# [Errno 2]: No such file or directory problem

Tags: python, import, file-not-found, errno, filenotfounderror

My code is so short and easy. I was trying to do an exercise about 'uses of time' in the course when I'm learning and I have to use the library: datetime, so I imported that but the problem is the next (Import here my code):

```
#ACTV. 1
'''
difference in the age of two brothers
'''

#For manipulating time uses we gonna use <datetime> library
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

son1 = datetime (1985, 10, 20, 10, 55)
son2 = datetime (1992, 6, 25, 18, 30)

ages_dif = son1 - timedelta(son2)
print(ages_dif)
```

**The result:**

```
user@MacBook-Pro-de-user python_work %  /usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/user/.vscode
/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.8.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 49391 -- "/Users/
user/Documents/INFORMATICA/PROGRAMACION/python_work/\#DATOS TEMPORALES.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.8.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.8.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.8.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 237, in _get_code_from_file
    with io.open_code(decoded_path) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/Documents/INFORMATICA/PROGRAMACION/python_work/\\#DATOS TEMPORALES.py'
```

How I can find a solution because when this happens, I can't do anything, if I try to open another program this error appears again even if this code imports of not imports a library.

I have to say that I copy the code of datetime library in a .py file inside the same directory where the program which has the FileNotFoundError and the Error still appears.

Comment: Please do not include personal information or Spanish translation. I encourage you to visit our [help] and learn more about what makes great posts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi @molik - you are running this in UNIX correct? Think there is a problem in the command. You might be using `\` instead of `/` and there is hash before the filename? Error says that it is not able to find the file to run - it is not able to find this file to run - `/Users/user/Documents/INFORMATICA/PROGRAMACION/python_work/\\#DATOS TEMPORALES.py`

Comment: Not using the `#` symbol in your file name will make this much easier for you.

Comment: Hi @Redox I was using this code in a iOS and is in this PC where I have this type of Error. I don't know the reason about '\\' before the filename.
The case is that I try to run the same code in my old Windows and the error doesn't appear, there is not a FileNotFoundError in this PC

Comment: Hi @DanGetz I think the problem was here, because I just renamed the file and apparently, the code is running without problems. Why happened that? Maybe '#' encoded my file in iOS? Because I was able to run the code in Windows without problems...

Comment: You put a \ before the `#` when you tried to run it, that's what gave you the error. But it's not normal to have #s in file names, so it's easiest to just not do that.

Comment: @DanGetz I dont put a \ before the # when I called the file's name but I don't know why python in the error's text show it at that form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
diff = son2-son1   
#total_seconds gives the seconds 
diff.total_seconds()/(365*24*60*60) #divide by the number of seconds in a year
>6.685797184170472 #years
```